# PHP Sessions Mixing

Tags: php, session

I managed to get sessions working with PHP, however, the sessions are merging/mixing. If one user logs in and visits a certain page, and then a new user visits that same page, they will jump on to the first user's session.

My code is as follows:

```
session_start();
session_id();

$rainbow = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='" . $client->ID . "'");
$rainbow = mysqli_fetch_object($rainbow);
$_SESSION['Username'] = $rainbow->Username;
$_SESSION['Password'] = $rainbow->Password;
```

Every time a page is loaded, `session_start()` is called. I'm also using `session_id()` so I'm not sure why the sessions are merging.

This is becoming a large security problem.

Additionally, pages seem to be caching along with this issue, but it doesn't seem to be a session issue caused by caching. If you refresh the page, you will be placed back in your correct session and the page will be updated, otherwise, it will not.

Comment: Can you part of code how you are using session_id() ? and how session started ? seems your problem is there

Comment: session_start();
session_id();

Comment: $rainbow              = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='" . $client->ID . "'");
$rainbow              = mysqli_fetch_object($rainbow);
$_SESSION['Username'] = $rainbow->Username;
$_SESSION['Password'] = $rainbow->Password;

Comment: You no need to call session_id(); it just return back current session id. You can try folowwing trick to make sure that your sessions are ok or no. session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION['test_name']); $_SESSION['test_name'] = 55;

Comment: After removing session_id(); you aren't logged in at all.

Comment: I don't really got your problem ..., i guess you have to post your full php code. **Important:** Hide all your personal data before posting code

Comment: Start to debug the issue by inspecting HTTP requests directly from the browser's debugging tools and pay attention to when session cookies are being set and what session id is being used.

Comment: Tip - Never pass `passwords` to your sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You suppose your problem is that sessions are merged, but you misunderstand the situation. The sessions work correctly, but you save the same `username` and `password` as session variables.

You are using a variable called `$client`. You get a member from it, called `ID`. I am sure that you have a problem in initializing `$client`. Make sure that you initialize `$client` correctly, it has the correct `ID` for each session and that there is no potential for SQL injection.

Comment: I checked to make sure client is being initialized properly, and it is. Once you're logged in, it still puts you on to someone else's session before it destroys your session and logs you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this!

```
if($password === $password_from_database) {

    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['okayToken'] = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40, "^!hknvkisQwf@#$m);
    $_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();

}
```

Use the `$_SESSION['okayToken']` for session tracking purposes!
Never pass `passwords` to sessions. Not even the password hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem and for now, it's working. At a later time it'll need to be more unique though.

For now, I've given sessions a **key** which is simply the current UNIX timestamp.

This seems to be keeping the sessions unique, but as I said, it'll need to be more randomized in the future in case two users have the same timestamp, which would bring me back to the merging issue where the session is being confused.